# Out of Thin Air Safety

Tags: java, multithreading

[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.fr/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) explains this concept:

> When a thread reads a variable without synchronization, it may see a
>   stale value, but at least it sees a value that was actually placed
>   there by some thread rather than some random value. This safety
>   guarantee is called out-of-thin-air safety.

Is this type of safety weak since it may include a stale value?

Perhaps this snippet, `at least it sees a value that was actually placed there by some thread than some random value`, was mentioned since the book's previous topic was the possibility of the JVM to re-order variable statements in reference to `sharing variables without synchronization`?

Example: Depending on re-ordering: 42 or 0 could print out.

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while(!ready)  
                Thread.yield();
            System.out.println(number);
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    }
}
```

**EDITED** - removed "please comment" remark.

Comment: _Please comment on_ is not a good way to start an SO question. Do you have a specific question for us to answer?

Comment: Seems off topic to me?  "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @Keppil - good point, thanks. I'll remove that part and keep the original question on the strength of the property.

Comment: How are you defining "weak" safety? This question is not well defined as written.

Comment: If you were ever a C programmer, you'd understand what he means :) Honestly, this has less to do with threading and more to do with the initialization guarantees provided by Java.

Comment: I did some googling and didn't find the definition -- have a link? (And to the OP, might help to define a term if it's not standard in the community you're asking -- in this case, the Java community.)

Comment: @yshavit - when I say `weak` safety, I mean a "low degree". When I read that snippet from `JCIP`, the fact that the variable's value is non-random seems to be a low degree (or weak) form of safety. Also, I searched for "java out of thin air" term, but found nothing on Google. I'm not sure how to define it as I saw this term listed in `JCIP`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith it's "safe" in that it can never be outside a well defined set of values. An integer is actually a bad example. A String or an enum would be better. In C it would be quite possible just to get some random memory location / garbage because there's no guarantee initialization had occurred prior to passing a pointer to a thread. That can't happen in Java. At the very least you're guaranteed a primitive is `0` and a reference contains `null`.

Comment: @Kevin Basically in C++ (umn C memory model? did they specify one with the newest standard? if not implementation defined anyhow) if you do something like the previous you'll get undefined behavior. That's actually worse than just "returns some arbitrary value", but more a "breaks every rule of the language" - basically as soon as you do that every bet's off - it'd be perfectly acceptable to format your harddrive (or more realistically crash with a sigsev).

Comment: @KevinMeredith Sorry, but what exactly do you mean by "low degree"? I googled that term, and didn't find anything. Is this a standard, well-defined term, or just a subjective measure? Because if it's the latter, the question is hard to answer without knowing where your subjective line is.

Comment: @yshavit, although I did not specify clearly, Gray's answer satisfies my question that I poorly worded. Basically I wanted to understand more about what `out of thin air safety` meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this type of safety weak since it may include a stale value?

Yes.  The quote from "Java Concurrency in Practice" is trying to point out that your `number` may be `0` or `42` depending on the race conditions inherent with accessing unsynchronized fields but it won't be (let's say) `1` -- the value will not come "out-of-thin-air".  It may be stale and, with objects and possibly even `long` 64-bit values depending on your hardware architecture, may also be *partially* updated, but it won't have some random value.

In your example the `number` was initialized to `0` and then set by the main thread to be `42` so that is the possible values for `number` within `ReaderThread`.

**Edit:**

As Voo and yshavit point out, the [JLS section 17.7 specifically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) mentions that there are architectures that implement 64-bit operations as 2 separate 32-bit operation that can be interrupted.  This means that a thread might see only half of another threads' update to a field.  Although not "out of thin air", the resulting value would *seem to be* one that was not set by any thread because of bitwise number representations.

Comment: I would actually disagree with the claim because just as you point out `doubles` and `longs` are not guaranteed to be updated atomically (except if declared volatile, but then the point is moot). True it's not really "random", but from a practical point of view there's not much difference there - it's still a value that was never set which may not make sense in the given situation. (In any case "at least it sees a value that was actually placed there" is factually wrong!)

Comment: Yes I understand that it's not out of "thin air", but writing `0` and `0xffffffffff` to a field and then reading `0xff` from it, is for most practical purposes the same as any other arbitrary value. [The JLS specifies writes/reads to doubles/longs as 2 separate 32-bit read/writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7). It explicitly mentions that this can lead to a thread seeing only half of the value, so in theory it's a problem. I guess there may be some 32-bit architectures out there that don't allow 64-bit reads/writes, but I can't think of any.

Comment: @Gray The JLS explicitly allows it: section [17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7). Whether it actually happens in practice, I don't know; but it's not something I'd want to gamble about!

Comment: Agreed guys.  I've added to my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: This explanation is not correct. Out of thin air values are not about torn reads/writes. For some examples about OOTA check "JSR-133" Java Memory Model and Thread specification" page 19.

Comment: I wasn't saying that they were @pveentjer.   I looked at page 19 and didn't see anything applicable.  You talking about page 14-15?  It mentions quite plainly that r1 == r2 == 42 is not allowed (in JSR-133 not the OP).  That was the point of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

"Out-of-thin-air safety" is indeed a much weaker guarantee than e.g. "sequential consistency", but in some sense one might call it "strong." Namely, if your system provides OOTA-safety, you can reason about your programs **much** better than if your system didn't provide it. If you're using a system that doesn't provide OOTA-safety, you're basically screwed.

Hans Boehm and Brian Demsky recently wrote a paper on the topic titled "Outlawing ghosts: avoiding out-of-thin-air results"  [(PDF available on ACM.org).](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2618134) They give some *really* good examples of how a non-OOTA-safe system might work, and what kinds of bugs might crop up in such a system.

The basic idea is that some systems are allowed to do **speculative execution**, including speculative stores to memory (cache) which can later be undone if the system's speculation turns out to be incorrect. This works great in single-threaded systems, but in multi-threaded systems it is possible for two threads' speculations to feed on each other, creating a **"runaway rumor mill"**: Processor A believes that x=42 because Processor B speculatively stored 42 there, but Processor B only stored x=42 because Processor A told it that y=17... but Processor A was merely speculating based on the assumption that x=42!

```
void rivera() {                 void lemon() {
    if (x == 42) {                  if (y == 17) {
        y = 17;                         x = 42;
    }                               }
}                               }
```

A "non-OOTA-safe" system might rewrite these methods to look like (in pseudo-Python-Javascript syntax, sorry)

```
void rivera() {
    assert(y not in cache);  // for the sake of argument
    cache.y = 17;  // for the sake of speed, speculatively report that y=17
    if (x not in cache) {
        cache.x = x;  // meanwhile, slowly fetch the real value of x
    }
    if (cache.x != 42) {
        delete cache.y;  // discard the earlier, speculative write
    }
    // and then later write cache.y back into the y in main memory
}
```

You can see how it would be a huge problem if `lemon()` trusted `rivera()`'s speculative report that `cache.y = 17` and vice versa. We could end up, after both methods have completed, with the situation that `x=42` and `y=17` even when neither of them started out that way!

I know people usually rely on [time-travel paradox](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68301/what-paradox-is-this-scenario) metaphors to describe how the values 42 and 17 end up in main memory "out of thin air", but I think the cable-news metaphor is more accurate. ;)